# How to build boost foreach cycle

Tags: c++, boost, foreach, virtual, call

I have some abstract class called **IClass** (has pure virtual function). There are some classes which inherit **IClass**: **CFirst**, **CSecond**.
I want to add objects of classes which inherit into **boost::ptr_vector**:

```
class IClass { virtual void someFunc() = 0; };
class CFirst : public IClass { };
class CSecond : public IClass { };

boost::ptr_vector<IClass> objectsList;

objectsList.push_back(new CFirst());
objectsList.push_back(new CSecond());
```

And now my goal is to call function (which is declarated in **IClass**) from all objects in **objectsList**. I'd prefer to use **BOOST_FOREACH**:

```
foreach(IClass tempObj, objectsList)
{
    tempObj.someFunc();
}
```

The problem is that **IClass** - abstract class, so I can't make instance of it for the foreach-cycle. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a reference to `IClass` instead:

```
foreach(IClass& tempObj, objectsList)
{
    tempObj.someFunc();
}
```